# Python regular expression for exact string length

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to write a regex that will get a hash currently I have the following regex that catches MD5 hashes

```
[0-9a-fA-F].{32}
```

However, this will also get the first 32 characters of a longer string such as a SHA-1 hash. I am wondering how I can edit this to ensure that it only matches if the string is 32 characters long and not 40 characters?

EDIT: Sorry I should have said I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Use anchors (`^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$`) or `re.fullmatch`

Comment: Why do you use dot here?

Comment: @Dmitry exactly: that would match 33 characters in the current state (Sebastian has updated his comment :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match md5 hash as a whole string use *start/end of the string* anchors `^`, `$`:

```
s = "3b4e1a15682994ef0bb2cbea8abfa105"
result = re.search(r'^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$', s)

print result.group()   # 3b4e1a15682994ef0bb2cbea8abfa105
```

---

To match md5 hash as a substring(part of the text) use word boundaries `\b`:

```
s = "hash 3b4e1a15682994ef0bb2cbea8abfa105 some text"
result = re.search(r'\b[0-9a-fA-F]{32}\b', s)

print result.group()    # 3b4e1a15682994ef0bb2cbea8abfa105
```

Comment: @user7399815, this is really strange behaviour, but it would match 128 bit hash with `re.search(r'\b[0-9a-fA-F]{127}\b', s)`

Answer (score 2):

There is a little (but all to important) mistake in your regex - `[0-9a-fA-F].{32}` matches one hex character and then 32 of any characters (except newline). Your pattern should thus be `[0-9a-fA-F]{32}`

To check that the whole string is matched you can either use `re.fullmatch` ([added in Python 3.4](https://bugs.python.org/issue16203)) or use anchors `^` (start of the string) and `$` (end of the string)

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste some example strings (each of length 32 and 40)?

Without the example I can think of making use of `^` and `$` to match the beginning of the string and end of the string as explained in the [Python re tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html).

Example:

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$
```

Comment: Here are some examples of hashes length 32 (MD5) & 40 (SHA-1). 9c3aec2376f1052a95d8de480a37572f  ,  
566dd7d858598375eaa7f468379447c673d934e2